# Rgexf dynamic node attributes

Tags: r, dynamic, attributes, gephi

I'm trying to build a dynamic gexf graph-file using the R library Rgexf. It is great so far but I would like to add node attributes changing over time. As I understand it the gexf format supports this but I don't know how to add this using the R library.

Is this possible with rgexf?
If not which would be another way to do it? 
I have some basic python knowlegde would pygexf a mor powerfull alternative?

Comment: Do you want to add a dynamic nodes? or a dynamic attribute to a node?

Comment: I want to add a dynamic attribute to a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As author/developer of rgexf I can tell you that for the current version it is not possible handling spells or dynamic attributes. The next version will (hoping to have it in the next two weeks).

For now you can try using Paul Girard's pygexf (gexf for python) https://github.com/paulgirard/pygexf , which supports spells.

Here you will fine a really good example of network dynamics with spells and dynamic attributes http://gexf.net/format/dynamics.html

If you have another concern/suggestion about the library please do not hesitate to send me an email at george [dot] vega [at] nodoschile.org . I would be very grateful.

Best wishes

George Vega

Comment: that sounds great! by the the way thank you for this great library! I will stay with R and rgexf as you say th requested feature will be included in the near future. Another question would be, if gephi will be able to visualize these changes in node attributes over time. I tried this with the example gexf file you are referring to and it seems that it does not.

Comment: Thanks for supporting my project =)... About gephi supporting this GEXF feature, it does. Just check out the data lab and you'll see the "indegree" attribute with spells and different values over time intervals. In order to visualize this in the graph itself, you should check out this post in the gephi forum https://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=1986 in general terms you have to apply size/color definition (based on attributes) continuosly while playing the dynamics timeline. I did try it with nodes size and it worked. Let me know if it helps. Cheers!